# Incorrect syntax error near 'email'

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, email, syntax

I'm running Visual studio and whenever I run my application it says "Incorrect syntax error near '(the email i enter appears here)'". I hope you can spot the mistake.

Within SQL server, my email column is called 'email'

Within Visual studio, the name of the input field for my email is called 'textEmail'

```
Public Sub AddCustomer(Firstname As String, Surname As String, Contactnum As String, Email As String)
    Try
        Dim strInsert As String = "INSERT INTO customers (firstname, surname, contactnum, email) " & _
                                  "VALUES  (" & _
                                  "'" & Firstname & "'," & _
                                  "'" & Surname & "'," & _
                                  "'" & Contactnum & "'," & _
                                  "'" & Email & "'"

        MsgBox(strInsert)

        SQLCon.Open()
        SQLcmd = New SqlCommand(strInsert, SQLCon)

        SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


        SQLCon.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try





End Sub

End Class
```

Code within form:

```
    Private Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
    'QUERY FOR CUSTOMER
    SQL.RunQuery("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customers.email = '" & txtEmail.Text & "' ")

    If SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox("This Email alredy exists!")
        Exit Sub
    Else
    CreateCustomer()
    End If
End Sub

      Public Sub CreateCustomer()
    ' ADD CUSTOMER TO DATABASE
    SQL.AddCustomer(txtFirst.Text, txtSur.Text, txtNum.Text, txtEmail.Text)


End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to [parameterise your SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing closing bracket

```
Dim strInsert As String = "INSERT INTO customers (firstname, surname, contactnum, email) " & _
                                  "VALUES  (" & _
                                  "'" & Firstname & "'," & _
                                  "'" & Surname & "'," & _
                                  "'" & Contactnum & "'," & _
                                  "'" & Email & "')"
```